How to generate SDP offer to get live stream from Camera(wired) WebRTC
Hi i am newish to programing and I'm currently working on a project to access the live stream video of my nest cam on an android device. I am using java in android studio. I have been able to make the API calls using volly to gather device-id and access token however I'm stuck at generating the offerSDP. I am confused on what is needed to make this connection to the camera as many examples of WebRTC I've seen online are for creating video calling applications however because this is with an API I'm not sure what i actually need. I've also seen googles code example however that's in JavaScript and I'm not sure how to translate it down to java. I have attempted to create an offer but keep getting errors. Any help would be much appreciated.
I've tried hardcoding a whole SDP offer but it still didn't work and i tried hardcoding with the example offer google gives in their documentation but still no luck.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am looking for a way to generate an SDP offer that matches Google's restrictions in android.
